# redirect_to vs. render - Michael Hartl's tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Going through Hartl's tutorial, at **Listing 10.42** in microposts controller we have

```
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

so in `else` branch we need to put empty `@feed_items` because render
itself doesnt provide the variable.

My question is - why not use `redirect_to root_url` just like
in `if` branch, that way this variable would be provided by controller action?

Comment: Perhaps this article will help: [render vs. redirect_to in Ruby on Rails 3](http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3313). Although it's Rails 3, it should still apply.

Comment: I understand, vaguely, the difference between the two.
My question is - why did the author choose one over another here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `@micropost.save` returns `false`, it means your `@micropost` is not valid. In other words: you have validations errors. These errors can be accessed through `@micropost.errors`. You should display them in the view, so the user knows what he's done wrong. If you redirect it will be a completely new request and `@micropost.errors` won't be available anymore. That's why he's using render.

Another aspect of this is that you'll want to repopulate the form with the values the user inputted. If you redirect these values will also be gone. To preserve the errors and posted values through a redirect you'd have to save them in a session or something. It's much easier to just render the view instead.

Comment: The only requirement for the micropost is that it's not blank.

Comment: I think you may be right, I may accept it after couple more replies

Comment: Even if the only requirement is that it's not blank, I'd still use render instead of redirect. When redirecting you still have to do something "special" to inform the user that validation failed and that his micropost shouldn't be empty. If you use render, you can use the framework as it was intended: display the errors in `@micropost.errors` in the view without any additional effort.

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient since render will simply render the view, and will use the variables provided in this controller (as opposite to redirect_to which will make a new url request and will execute the requested controller + view).

This is the best solution for that particular example, not in general, so you will need to chose between redirect_to or render depending on what you want to do in your app.

Comment: I understand, vaguely, the difference between the two.
My question is - why did the author choose one over another here.

Comment: Because he doesn't need to do a url request and get variables from another control, when all he needs is already there. If he would need to redirect the user somewhere else, then probably a redirect_to would  have made more sense.